# Scala case class structure for complex xml

Tags: scala

xml data looks like

```
<bd>
   <oied>
      <oeuo>XYZWC999</oeuo>
      <oedo>SorNbteluk=ONRM_ROOT_MO_R,SrobeNhbwk=XYZWC999,MoetxeoCt=XYZWC999</oedo>
      <oesw>CXP9021776/2_R2CA15</oesw>
   </oied>
   <bi>
      <bts>20150205141500Z</bts>
      <gp>900</gp>
      <bt>paaoCukStSteboshRrttcps</bt>
      <bt>pptubthCaStctoSekSos</bt>
      <bv>
         <biod>MaebdlgeaooeEt=1,TparswotterNorok=1,Ntcp=Kub-9</biod>
         <r>4578</r>
         <r>10769</r>
      </bv>
      <bv>
         <biod>MEegoedbaaloet=1,TreatoorNtosrpwk=1,Ntcp=1</biod>
         <r>11021</r>
         <r>86235</r>
      </bv>
      <bv>
         <biod>MdaolaeeobeEgt=1,TretrowooNrtsapk=1,Nctp=Kub-7</biod>
         <r>0</r>
         <r>0</r>
      </bv>
   </bi>
</bd>
```

I am new to Scala, I could figure out the basic structure.

```
case class xmldata(oeuo : String, oedo : String, oesw: String, bts: String, gp : Int, btArray : List[String])
```

What is the optimized Scala case class (with collections) for this xml data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just tree of case classes:

```
case class Bd(oied: Oied, bi: Bi)
case class Oied(oeuo: String, oedo: String, oesw: String)
case class Bi(bts: String, gp: String, bt: List[String], bv: List[Bv])
case class Bv(biod: String, r: List[String])
```

If order doesn't matter - you might use `Set` instead of `List`

You also might flatten it a bit (like in your solution), but it could be harder to map it with xml-binding tools then

```
case class Bd(oeuo: String, oedo: String, oesw: String, bts: String, gp: String, bt: List[String], bv: List[Bv])
```

The most flattened and least operable version (not recommended):

```
case class Bd(oeuo: String, oedo: String, oesw: String, bts: String, gp: String, bt: List[String], biods: List[String], rs: List[List[String]])
```